# I can't search for the tags Git + Visual-Studio. Why?

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

On Stack Overflow, if I search for the tag Git I get 3,947 questions tagged. If I search for the tags Git + Windows, I get 80 questions tagged. It's what I am looking for.

But I can't search for the tags Git + Visual-Studio. Why?

For example, there is at least [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) with Git + Visual-Studio tag:

Comment: What type of error are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list of all questions tagged [visual-studio] and [git]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio+git

Comment: How do you success to do that ?
Yes your link works.
But I cant do it by myself.
Please explain.

Comment: Do I have to build in a editor my own link, and copy and pass it ?

Comment: @pierre normally you'd just click [git] in the related tags in the sidebar from the [visual-studio] questions page, but [git] isn't in the top (n) related tags for [visual-studio]

Answer (score 6):

Just type `[visual-studio] [git]` in the search bar.

You can search for a tag using `[tagname]`. If you put more than one, you search for more than one. See https://stackoverflow.com/search for more options.